# Alternative for looking up a column in 2 tables for JOIN and looking up each column in both tables joined by FULL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
WITH 
T1 AS (
SELECT 'GL001' AS GLCode, 'D001' AS DeptCode, 'OB001-1' AS OpAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL001' AS GLCode, 'D004' AS DeptCode, 'OB001-2' AS OpAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL003' AS GLCode, 'D005' AS DeptCode, 'OB003-1' AS OpAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL003' AS GLCode, NULL AS DeptCode, 'OB003-2' AS OpAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL003' AS GLCode, '' AS DeptCode, 'OB003-3' AS OpAmt
),
T2 AS (
SELECT 'GL002' AS GLCode, 'D007' AS DeptCode, 'NET002' AS NetAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL003' AS GLCode, 'D008' AS DeptCode, 'NET003-1' AS NetAmt
UNION 
SELECT 'GL003' AS GLCode, 'D005' AS DeptCode, 'NET003-2' AS NetAmt
),
T3 AS (
SELECT 'D001' AS DeptCode, 'DName001' AS DeptName
UNION
SELECT 'D002' AS DeptCode, 'DName002' AS DeptName
UNION
SELECT 'D004' AS DeptCode, 'DName004' AS DeptName
UNION
SELECT 'D005' AS DeptCode, 'DName005' AS DeptName
UNION
SELECT 'D007' AS DeptCode, 'DName007' AS DeptName
UNION
SELECT 'D008' AS DeptCode, 'DName008' AS DeptName
)
SELECT ISNULL(T1.GLCode, T2.GLCode) AS GLCode, ISNULL(T1.DeptCode, T2.DeptCode) AS DeptCode, 
T3.DeptName, 
T1.OpAmt, T2.NetAmt
FROM 
(T1 FULL JOIN T2 ON T1.GLCode = T2.GLCode AND T1.DeptCode = T2.DeptCode)

LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON (T1.DeptCode = T3.DeptCode OR (T1.DeptCode IS NULL AND T2.DeptCode = T3.DeptCode)) 
WHERE T1.OpAmt IS NOT NULL OR T2.NetAmt IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY GLCode, DeptCode
```

1. Is there any alternative for avoiding 2 table lookups for each column like GLCode, DeptCode, etc in the table resultant out of the FULL JOIN?
2. Is there any alternative for looking up DeptCode from one of the 2 tables T1 and T2 in the condition: `LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON (T1.DeptCode = T3.DeptCode OR (T1.DeptCode IS NULL AND T2.DeptCode = T3.DeptCode))`

Comment: Is there an alternative to `ISNULL`? Yes; `COALESCE` has similar (but not identical) behaviour. You can't, however, get around the need to return a different column when the first column has the value `NULL`.

Comment: So in the above example of FULL JOIN, I must necessarily use 2 tables for each column in the output?

Comment: *"I must necessarily use 2 tables for each column in the output?"* I don't know what you mean by this.

Comment: If I want to output the value of GLCode and DeptCode in each row, do I have to necessarily refer to both T1 and T2 tables (either using COALESCE or ISNULL)?

Comment: Yes, you can't just have `GLCode` as that would be ambiguous, and `G1.GLCode` would (unsurprisingly) return `NULL` if `G1.GLCode` had the value `NULL`. You *need* to define that you want `G2.GLCode` when the value of `G1.GLCode` has the value `NULL`.

Comment: ok, and then for the JOIN condition for DeptCode too, I must necessarily refer to both T1 and T2 tables, right?

Comment: Again, same reasons.

Comment: ok then, is there any best practice here? Is it better to introduce an intermediate table which collects the result of FULL JOIN of T1 and T2, so that the further JOINs to T3 or any other table do not require fetching values from multiple tables for DeptCode and other columns?

Comment: You could use a `CTE` or derived table, or `INSERT` the data into a temporary table, if you wanted to, yes. If the performance would be better/worse would be up to you to test.